# My Web application gives CORS error after adding HTTPS using Let's Encrypt

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, https, reverse-proxy

This is my application: https://cfslpro.com/student_portal/. Front end is done by AngularJS and back end is done by Node.JS. Hosted in Apache server. (Digital ocean Linux 16.04).

You can try logging in; the username is chanu and the password is 123456.
Before adding SSL using Let's Encrypt, this application worked well.
Now I'm getting this error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

But you can run this URL without HTTPS on browser and it's working :

> http://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login

Now I will show you some important sections in my Node.Js server code :

This is how I'm adding CORS plugin.

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

And this is how I create HTTP server :

```
app.listen(config.port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
   } else {
        console.log("localhost:7000");
    }
});
```

i'm creating a HTTP normal server here.

And this is how I'm calling login end point from my front end.

> https://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login

If I use this without HTTPS, I'm getting an error about `content blocked` because I can't call HTTP request from HTTPS environment. This is where I get CORS error.

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/cfslpro.com.conf` file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        <Directory /var/www/cfslpro.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

        </Directory>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName cfslpro.com
        ServerAlias www.cfslpro.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/cfslpro.com/public_html

        ProxyRequests on
        ProxyPass http://165.227.121.28:7000/api/user_manage/login https://localhost:7000/api/user_manage/login

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I think my reverse proxy configuration is wrong. I'm new to this proxy configuration and i followed some online examples. I followed this example too : http://www.codingtricks.biz/run-nodejs-application-apache/

This is my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
</IfModule>
```

Why is this CORS giving me these errors and issues? I'm someone who is trying to fix and learn.

Comment: You'll need a vhost on port 443 to get a secure connection working. It also has to be on a domain and not an IP, at least if you want to run a valid certificate.

Comment: Also, in Firefox, it does not seem to be making an HTTP request at all. That might be because of the CORS issue - however the bare URL (in a GET operation) returns 404, and there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header there. Are you using POST to do the login?

Comment: (Also, three questions on the same topic in two days is excessive. Ask one question, and try not to ask essentially duplicate questions).

Comment: @halfer Can you please explain me this ? " It also has to be on a domain.." I run Node server in a IP with a port. can you please show me an example ?

Comment: @halfer "Access-Control-Allow-Origin header there.".. How to fix this ?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only obtain valid SSL certificates (from a certificate authority) on a domain, not an IP address. That might not affect the CORS issue, but it still won't work. Do you actually need the main web server and AJAX server to be on different domains? I wonder if you should just use a frontend proxy to make them seem as though they are on the same domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After adding HTTPS , my servers are not working and getting CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756621/after-adding-https-my-servers-are-not-working-and-getting-cors-error)

Comment: If you were to use a frontend proxy, you could reserve the path `https://cfslpro.com/api/` to be forwarded to your Node server, and you would have no CORS issue to deal with.

Comment: @halfer can you please tell me how to do that "https://cfslpro.com/api/" in reverse proxy system ? please one example ? Like this 
ProxyPass https://cfslpro.com/api/ https://localhost:7000/api/user_manage/login    , using https ?

Comment: No, it's too broad for an example. I encourage you to do some research, try something, and ask a question if you get stuck. You can do this either with an Apache `Location` directive, or mod_rewrite with a proxy flag does it (that's how I did this last time I needed to). If you ask a new question and have researched it, ping me with the link and I will take a look.